# !empty PHP function doesn't work for SQL queries

Tags: php, sql

IF I use the !empty() on an sql query it doesn't say it is empty even if no rows are returned. e.g.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql_ideas);
if ( !empty($result)) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $highlights[] = array($row["summary"], $row["detail"]);
}   
-- Do stuff --
}
```

It just carries on as though a result is returned. Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: why do you even need the check?

Comment: because if the query returns values I want to to complete some HTML, if it doesn't go to the next query...

Comment: @StuartDurning this is where a row count comes in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using mysqli, your result object will actually be a 'mysqli result' - a class in it's own right. Checking that the row count is greater than zero is going to be the way to go.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm clearly being stupid.... but why doesn't this error then ...
    ``if ( (mysql_num_rows($result)) > 0)``

Comment: Or this... ``$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ( $num_rows > 0) {'' 
...says 'mysql_num_rows expects parmeter 1 to be a resource'  ** Previous comment meant to say why DOES this error then.

Comment: I just needed to put it aftet my fetch_assoc() statement. So thanks!